# Column not found: 1054 :Unknown column 'employee' in 'field list' in MySQL when use nova-repeatable-fields

Tags: laravel-nova

I use nova-repeatable-fields package for add more functionality. When I save data, "Unknown column 'employees' in 'field list'" error comes. employee field is not in database. My code like this:

```
Repeater::make('Employees')
->addField([
    'label' => 'Full name',
    'name' => 'full_name',
    'type' => 'text',
    'placeholder' => 'Full Name',
])
->addField([
    'label' => 'ID No',
    'name' => 'id_no',
    'type' => 'text',
    'placeholder' => 'ID No',
])
->addButtonText('Add')
->displayStackedForm(),
```

[Please show image for better understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUjVI.png)

Comment: Which table column you are trying to save? Can you please provide the table structure

Comment: My table name is employees and field are full_name and id_no.

Comment: The package is for one field in the model, which is one column in the table. The way you are using is incorrect. You can use nova fields like `Text::make('Full Name', 'full_name'), Text::make('ID No, 'id_no')`

Comment: bt i want to use this two field as repeatable (ADD more) .so i use nova-repeatable-fields package.

Comment: You can use this package when you have a column which stores array of details. For example `employees` table has `address` column, where you are going to store multiple addresses like following `[{'address1': 'No 5.', 'city': 'NY', 'country': 'USA'}, {'address1': 'No 10.', 'city': 'IN', 'country': 'USA'}]`, then you can use `repeater` to add multiple address (`address1`, `city`, `country`)

Comment: In your case I understand that you are trying to do bulk creation (multiple entries in one table in one go). So far I have not seen

Comment: okay. Thanks.@SauminiNavaratnam